Selenium Webdriver for Unity Android Game
I want to make a unity game that requires to go to a website and interact with it in the background (something like selenium in headless mode would handle in c# dotnet for example).
Is there an equivalent or a way to use selenium and it's webdriver features (find elements by html/css, interacting with buttons and textfields) inside of unity with android as a target platform (compiled as .apk file)?
I have no idea what to do. I know you can use regular Selenium in Unity but I think that only works for desktop application and not for android (correct me if I'm wrong).
I need something like Selenium Webdriver but for Unity 3D with android as the target platform.

Interacting with another system ("website") is normally done through APIs. Using Selenium to do this is a horrible idea, guaranteed to be unreliable.

As already mentioned by @SiKing, using selenium for this might not be a good idea.
Alternatives could be:

using the android-WebView
Build and customize Chromium-android based on your needs

